# Having trouble finding the limit of a sequence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm having a bit of trouble with this problem. I tried writing down the first few terms explicitly but that doesn't seem to be working.

This is the sequence for when n is approaching infinity:

$\frac{25}{20^{n}} + 16\mathrm{arctan}(n^{6})$

Answer (score 1):

As $n\to\infty$, $20^n\to+\infty$ and $n^6\to+\infty$. Therefore, we have 
$$\frac{25}{20^n}+16\arctan(n^6)=0+16(\frac{\pi}{2})=8\pi$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks I was wondering what arctan would be as n approaches infinity.

Comment: $\arctan(x)$ goes to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as $x$ goes to $+\infty$, as you can see from this graph: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#mediaviewer/File:Arctangent_Arccotangent.svg

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate the limits by parts and then sum them since they exists, so

$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(25/20^n+16\arctan(n^6))=25/20^{\infty}+16\arctan(\infty^6)=25/\infty+16\arctan(\infty)\\$ $=0+16(\pi/2)=8\pi$